# Training DQN Agent slows down and then at around 50 episodes crashes

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I am training a DQN Agent at around 50 episodes the fit in the replay function starts slowing down and starts freezing the PC. After a while PyCharm just crashes. The epochs start going from 10-13ms to seconds and eventually it freezes entirely

This is the relevant part of the agent The input is just an array with 12 different floats

```
    def __init__(self, agent_config):
        self.agent_config = agent_config
        self.state_size = agent_config['state_size']
        self.discount_factor = agent_config['discount_factor']
        self.action_size = agent_config['action_size']
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=agent_config['memory_size'])
        self.epsilon = agent_config['epsilon']
        self.learning_rate = agent_config['learning_rate']
        self.model = self._build_model()
        self.target_model = self._build_model()

    def _build_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss=keras.losses.Huber(), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate))
        return model

    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.random() > self.epsilon:
            actions = self.model.predict(state)
            return np.argmax(actions[0])
        else:
            return np.random.randint(0, self.action_size)

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def replay(self, batch_size):
        minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

        X = []
        y = []

        for index, (state, action, reward, next_state, done) in enumerate(minibatch):

            current_q = self.model.predict(state)
            future_q = self.target_model.predict(next_state)

            if not done:
                max_future_q = np.max(future_q)
                new_q = reward + self.discount_factor + max_future_q
            else:
                new_q = reward

            current_q[0][action] = new_q

            X.append(state[0])
            y.append(current_q)

        self.model.train_on_batch(np.array(X), np.array(y))
```

Here is the training loop:

```
def train_dqn(agent, env: gym.Env, episodes: int, batch_size: int, episode_length: int):

    ep_rewards = []
    aggr_ep_rewards = {'ep': [], 'avg': [], 'max': [], 'min': []}
    STATS_EVERY = 5

    START_EPSILON_DECAYING = 1
    END_EPSILON_DECAYING = episodes // 2
    epsilon_decay_value = agent.epsilon / (END_EPSILON_DECAYING - START_EPSILON_DECAYING)

    for episode in range(episodes):
        total_reward = 0
        # reset state in the beginning of each game
        state = env.reset()
        state = encode_state(state)
        # Loop over time steps until the episode is done or the time limit is reached
        for i in range(episode_length):
            action = agent.act(state)
            decoded_action = decode_action(action, state, env.action_space)
            next_state, reward, done, _, _ = env.step(decoded_action)
            encoded_next_state = encode_state(next_state)
            agent.remember(state, action, reward, encoded_next_state, done)
            state = encoded_next_state
            total_reward += reward
            if (episode * 30) % 90 == 0:
                if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
                    agent.replay(batch_size)
            if (episode * 30) % 450 == 0:
                agent.target_model.set_weights(agent.model.get_weights())

        ep_rewards.append(total_reward)

        if not episode % STATS_EVERY:
            average_reward = sum(ep_rewards[-STATS_EVERY:]) / STATS_EVERY
            aggr_ep_rewards['ep'].append(episode)
            aggr_ep_rewards['avg'].append(average_reward)
            aggr_ep_rewards['max'].append(max(ep_rewards[-STATS_EVERY:]))
            aggr_ep_rewards['min'].append(min(ep_rewards[-STATS_EVERY:]))
            print(
                f'Episode: {episode:>5d}, average reward: {average_reward:>4.1f}, current epsilon: {agent.epsilon:>1.2f}')

        if END_EPSILON_DECAYING >= episode >= START_EPSILON_DECAYING:
            if agent.epsilon - epsilon_decay_value >= 0:
                agent.epsilon -= epsilon_decay_value

        print("episode: {}/{}, score: {}, e: {:.2}"
              .format(episode, episodes, total_reward, agent.epsilon))

        if episode % 10 == 0:
            agent.save(f"models/model_{episode}.h5")

    plt.plot(aggr_ep_rewards['ep'], aggr_ep_rewards['avg'], label="average rewards")
    plt.plot(aggr_ep_rewards['ep'], aggr_ep_rewards['max'], label="max rewards")
    plt.plot(aggr_ep_rewards['ep'], aggr_ep_rewards['min'], label="min rewards")
    plt.legend(loc=4)
    plt.show()
    agent.save(f"model_{episodes}.h5")
    return agent
```

I've tried different batch sizes, different sizes for the memory and changing the frequency of the replay function. The effect of this was that smaller batch size and frequency makes it crash later in the training. Changing the size of the neural net has no effect.
I added 16gb extra RAM and this helped but now it crashes at around 245 episodes.
With the model.fit function it crashes at 210. With train on batch it crashes at 245.
Installing CUDA and using a GPU instead of CPU made zero difference.
What could cause this? Is this something in my code or is this an issue with my pc or operating system?
I originally asked this on ai.stackexchange but was redirected to stackoverflow.

Comment: it seems you have a good question, but it is missing info, the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm afraid that won't be possible since this code is a part of something much bigger which I can't share

Comment: understood.  however, it is difficult for others to help constructively without the minimum basic information.

Comment: Yeah I get that. I guess I could also just save the models and the memory every 200 episodes and then restart the training process that should work theoretically. 
Seems to me like there is a memory leak somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your hardware is still not powerful enough to handle computation for training. Although the code looks good, but there could be some improvements that you could try.

You could experiment with different replay schedules and see how they affect the agent's performance or try changing the loss function to 'MSE'. Maybe it would still be ineffective. I suggest trying a cloud-based service, maybe that could help with the crashes.